# Search for files created at specific time in folder OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, shell

I have a folder with 2000+ image files in it from a time lapse camera.  I want to find/select all the images that were taken at the time 10:00 and 15:00.  The find function has a "date created" but I want "time created" which I can't find.  These image files span a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install ImageMagick utils and use `identify` command for that.

You can install it via `brew install ImageMagick`.

Here is the suggestion how you can use this tool:

```
identify -verbose *.jpg | grep -we ^Image -e exif:DateTime | grep -C1 " [1-5].:..:"
```

It should print the files matching the criteria in format like:

```
Image: Foo.jpg
    exif:DateTime: 2015:02:31 11:00:00
```

To search for all files recursively, use [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) which is `**/*.jpg` (it's available in Bash 4.x, zsh and similar shells).